# MYSQL db returns wrong count

Tags: php, mysql, count, mysqli, prepared-statement

This piece of code returns 1 every time even if there is no given email address in db table. As you I place die($count) right after bind_result. It returns 1 every time. Have you noticed any wrong in my code?

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `users` WHERE `email`=? LIMIT 1") or die($db->error);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email) or die ($stmt->error);
    $stmt->execute() or die ($stmt->error);
    $count=$stmt->bind_result($count) or die ($stmt->error);
            die($count);
            $stmt->close();
    return ($count > 0 ? true : false);
```

Comment: im not a php guy but it would seem that your query is returning 1 meaning the statement executed without errors. perhaps there is another php method which will return row count or a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't call `$stmt->fetch()` to put the result of the query into the bound variable $count.

The value of $count is therefore set to the return value of `$stmt->bind_result()` which is always true (1) or false (0).

See examples at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php, you use `bind_result()` to tell the statement what PHP variables to store results in, but you must fetch the results of the query as a separate call to `fetch()`.

---

Re comment:  *None of these functions return the result of your count.*

The functions return TRUE on success, and FALSE on failure.  They do not return the result of the query.  That's why you bind a variable, so the fetch can store the result in that variable as a side effect -- not as a return value.  You should not assign `$count=*anything*`.

Here's how your code should look:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `users` WHERE `email`=? LIMIT 1") 
    or die($db->error);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email) 
    or die ($stmt->error);
$stmt->execute() 
    or die ($stmt->error);
$stmt->bind_result($count)  // do not use return value
    or die ($stmt->error);
$stmt->fetch() // do not use return value
    or die ($stmt->error);
print ($count);
$stmt->close()
    or die ($stmt->error);
return ($count > 0 ? true : false);
```

Comment: used $count=$stmt->fetch() instead. same result

Answer (score 1):

`bind_result` binds variables to a prepared statement for result storage, and returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

```
$stmt->bind_result($count);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
return ($count > 0 ? true : false); // return $count > 0; would be ok.
```